# IE error -2147024882

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I am developing a web page with vb.net on the server side and some javascript on the .aspx page for google maps. The web page is a big GIS thing that maps out all of the block groups of Georgia within certain counties, so it's about 15MB of pure [latitude,longitude] points in a .js file. In chrome/firefox, the map loads up, then the script is loaded which triggers a callback to draw the polygons it defines, and the polygons are drawn onto the map. In IE, the map is loaded, and when the script is loaded the console has a `SCRIPT14: error -2147024882` on line 1. Everything displays correctly besides the polygons on the map. The structure of the .js file is a declaration of only a couple of variables.

```
var allPolys = [
    [
      //poly1 points
      [x1,y1],
      [x2,y2],
      ...
    ],
    [
      //next poly
      [x1,y1],
      ...
    ]
]
```

^^ is how each polygon is defined in the .js. Is this a size issue because all of the points are within a single array?

mapping code:

```
            function drawPolys() {
                for (var i = 0; i < allTracts.length; i++) {
                    var tract = "new google.maps.Polygon({ strokeWeight: 0.7, path: [";
                    for (var j = 0; j < allTracts[i].length; j++)
                        tract += " new google.maps.LatLng(" + allTracts[i][j][0] + "," + allTracts[i][j][1] + "),";
                    tract = tract.substring(0, tract.length - 1) + "], map: map });";
                    eval(tract);
                }

                //this is all for other 'multipolygons' that are in some maps
                var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'];

                for (var i = 0; i < multiPolys.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < multiPolys[i].length; j++) {
                        var subTract = "new google.maps.Polygon({ strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: '" + colors[i % colors.length] + "', fillColor: '" + colors[i % colors.length] + "', path: [";
                        for (var k = 0; k < multiPolys[i][j].length; k++)
                            subTract += " new google.maps.LatLng(" + multiPolys[i][j][k][0] + "," + multiPolys[i][j][k][1] + "),";
                        subTract = subTract.substring(0, subTract.length - 1) + "], map: map });";
                        eval(subTract);
                    }
                }
            }
```

In Chrome the page loads beautifully.

edit :
the new mapping function without eval()'s

```
            function drawPolys() {
                for (var i = 0; i < allTracts.length; i++) {
                    var path = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < allTracts[i].length; j++)
                        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(allTracts[i][j][0],allTracts[i][j][1]));
                    new google.maps.Polygon({ strokeWeight: 0.7, path: path, map: map });
                }

                var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white'];

                for (var i = 0; i < multiPolys.length; i++) {
                    var path = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < multiPolys[i].length; j++) {
                        path[j] = [];
                        for (var k = 0; k < multiPolys[i][j].length; k++)
                            path[j].push(new google.maps.LatLng(multiPolys[i][j][k][0],multiPolys[i][j][k][1]));
                    }
                    new google.maps.Polygon({ strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: colors[i % colors.length], fillColor: colors[i % colors.length], paths: path, map: map });
                }
            }
```

Comment: `eval(tract);` is not needed! Why are you using it when you can just call `new google.maps.LatLng`?

Comment: Is it possible to post either jsFiddle or a link to a running page that we can use to evaluate the problem? It's really hard to debug the problem with only a few lines of code and no context. Though I agree, eval isn't necessary here.

Comment: I think this is a "out of memory"-issue. What are the length of multiPolys and allTracts?

Comment: eval() isn't? I'll see if I can get it out of there. I figured I needed it since the number of points in the polygon varied. I guess I could loop it and alter the path property with push() or something. I will look into it. multiPolys is never more than 10. allTracts can be anywhere from 100-1000 depending on how much of the state I map. In the most recent tests, I can get it working with allTracts at 85 or so, but not at 125 or so. A few days ago, I had the map displaying 950 length of allTracts and about 10 multiPolys. The page is up at http://srds-dev.cviog.uga.edu/test/default3.html.

Comment: the page I posted is just the map off of the page I'm working on. Open in chrome for the view of what it is supposed to look like. the .js file is 'tracts.js' if you'd like to see that, too. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 13):

I believe I’ve found the exact cause of this error.

**EDIT: I believe this bug was fixed as of IE 10**

My testing suggests that IE will refuse to execute a Javascript file with more than 2<sup>16</sup>-3 numbers in it. So, if a .js file has **65533** numbers, IE will execute it. But if it contains **65534** or more numbers, you will get error `−2147024882`.

I put up a test case demonstrating this problem here:

http://ie-error-2147024882.s3.amazonaws.com/ie_error_-2147024882.html

The site I’m working on loads large sets of JSON data from Javascript files hosted on S3. At first I thought this was due to some Javascript source file size limitation in IE. But a bit of testing revealed that IE can handle .js files that were much, much bigger than the ones that were setting off this mysterious `−2147024882` error.

The workaround, in my case, was to encode ints and floats as strings when generating the .js files and use parseInt and parseFloat to interpret them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my Googling goes this seems to be an "out of memory"-issue:

"Error -2147024882 There is not enough memory available to perform the operation. - MAPI_E_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY (Microsoft Exchange Server Information Store)

Check the lengths in you're for loops (multiPolys and allTracts)

And also check the length of you're string tract and subTract, they might be too long

Comment: How long is the maximum length for a string? Do different browsers have different limitations on javascript data types?